# Json Deserialize Array

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am new to Json and trying to do some examples with it. I have Json data like this:

```
{
  "Title": "The Avengers",
  "Year": "2012",
  "Rated": "PG-13",
  "Released": "04 May 2012",
  "Runtime": "143 min",
  "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
  "Director": "Joss Whedon",
  "Writer": "Joss Whedon (screenplay), Zak Penn (story), Joss Whedon (story)",
  "Actors": "Robert Downey Jr., Chris Evans, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Hemsworth",
  "Plot": "Earth's mightiest heroes must come together and learn to fight as a team if they are going to stop the mischievous Loki and his alien army from enslaving humanity.",
  "Language": "English, Russian, Hindi",
  "Country": "USA",
  "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 38 wins & 79 nominations.",
  "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Ratings": [
    {
      "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
      "Value": "8.0/10"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
      "Value": "92%"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Metacritic",
      "Value": "69/100"
    }
  ],
  "Metascore": "69",
  "imdbRating": "8.0",
  "imdbVotes": "1,200,683",
  "imdbID": "tt0848228",
  "Type": "movie",
  "DVD": "25 Sep 2012",
  "BoxOffice": "$623,279,547",
  "Production": "Walt Disney Pictures",
  "Website": "http://marvel.com/avengers_movie",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

I can get the data and read it just fine but when it comes deserialize I get the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Deneme.Modeller.Main]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

This is my code

```
string url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=7663ce8e&t=Avengers";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse reply;
reply = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader returninfo = new StreamReader(reply.GetResponseStream());
string getinfo = returninfo.ReadToEnd();
List<Main> Info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Main>>(getinfo);
```

and for models this is first main:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Year { get; set; }
public string Rated { get; set; }
public string Released { get; set; }
public string Runtime { get; set; }
public string Genre { get; set; }
public string Director { get; set; }
public string Writer { get; set; }
public string Actors { get; set; }
public string Plot { get; set; }
public string Language { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }
public string Awards { get; set; }
public string Poster { get; set; }
public List<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
public string Metascore { get; set; }
public string imdbRating { get; set; }
public string imdbVotes { get; set; }
public string imdbID { get; set; }
public string Type { get; set; }
public string DVD { get; set; }
public string BoxOffice { get; set; }
public string Production { get; set; }
public string Website { get; set; }
public string Response { get; set; }
```

second one is for Ratings:

```
public string Source { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Main> Mains { get; set; }
```

It's about Json array, but I looked asked questions about this problem and tried to fix it but no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: A Json **array** will always start with a square bracket `[`, a Json **object** will always start with a curly bracket `{`. An **object** != **array**

Comment: @Selvin LOL thats right. I was like wtf when I saw the comments damn blindness. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize a single object of type `Main` into a list of objects.

You can either change your code to deserialize into a single object instead of a list or you can alter your JSON to represent an array of objects.

The first option would be

```
Main Info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Main>(getinfo);
```

And the second option

```
[{"Title":"The Avengers","Year":"2012","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"04 May 2012","Runtime":"143 min","Genre":"Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi","Director":"Joss Whedon","Writer":"Joss Whedon (screenplay), Zak Penn (story), Joss Whedon (story)","Actors":"Robert Downey Jr., Chris Evans, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Hemsworth","Plot":"Earth's mightiest heroes must come together and learn to fight as a team if they are going to stop the mischievous Loki and his alien army from enslaving humanity.","Language":"English, Russian, Hindi","Country":"USA","Awards":"Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 38 wins & 79 nominations.","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"8.0/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"92%"},{"Source":"Metacritic","Value":"69/100"}],"Metascore":"69","imdbRating":"8.0","imdbVotes":"1,200,683","imdbID":"tt0848228","Type":"movie","DVD":"25 Sep 2012","BoxOffice":"$623,279,547","Production":"Walt Disney Pictures","Website":"http://marvel.com/avengers_movie","Response":"True"}]
```

(simply add brackets)

Which option you have to choose is depending on your requirements, i.e. if you want to allow multiple objects or just one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Main Info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Main>(getinfo);
```

Your json string has only one Main object, you were trying to get a List

Answer (score 0):

#### You try to deserialize one JSON object into a list of objects.

This is an example of simple object:

```
{ "field": 123 }
```

To deserialize it you need to:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeModel>(json);
```

But if you have an array of objects:

```
[{ "field": 123 }, { "field": 123 }]
```

You will be able to deserialize them to a list like this:

```
var objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeModel[]>(json);
```

or

```
var objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SomeModel>>(json);
```

#### Solutions to your question:

- Change deserialization type to a single object.
- Wrap your JSON around with `[]`

Answer (score 0):

when we call api 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=7663ce8e&t=Avenger' we gets an objet  not an array of object

try

```cs
 var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Main>(getinfo);
```

If you want list of movies try a other api b.e.: [themoviedbAPI](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api)